# Parse single XML statement in string

Tags: c#, xml

I ahve experience serializing/deserializing XML files but I have never had to parse just a single statement, so I'm not sure how to go about this.

I have a string that holds this:

```
<Vol Model_Type="Flat">102.14</Vol>
```

And, I want to extract just the 102.14.

Should I use XPath, or is there a simpler option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or above, use LINQ to XML. For example:

```
string x = "<Vol Model_Type=\"Flat\">102.14</Vol>";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(x);
decimal value = (decimal) element;
```

XML handling doesn't get much simpler than that :)

Of course, that's assuming you don't care about the element name or the attribute. If you do, LINQ to XML will still make it easy for you.

Comment: Seems like just the thing I was looking for. I have using .NET 4.0. However, XElement does not seem to have the Parse property. I added System.Linq namespace. Anyways, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @xbonez: You need the System.Xml.Linq namespace, and XElement most definitely *does* have a Parse method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse.aspx

Comment: Strange. I added references to System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq and added the two namespaces, and get I get an error stating System.Xml.XmlElement' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'

Comment: Geez....nevermind. Intellisense autocorrected it to XmlElement instead of XElement. Works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
string x = "<Vol Model_Type=\"Flat\">102.14</Vol>";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(x);
decimal value=element.Value.Tostring();
```